# MsBuild.exe vs. Visual Studio 2017 different output

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have an issue when i build my project with Visual Studio 2017, everything is working just fine, but when trying to build the project with msbuild.exe the output is different and is not working.

**msbuild executed**

```
msbuild.exe "myproj.csproj" /p:Configuration=Release;Platform="Any CPU";OutputPath="c:\pub\myproj"
```

**Visual studio build settings:**
[image: Build settings in visual studio 2017]
Any sugestions what iam doing wrong, and how can I get the msbuild to make the same output as the Visual Studio build?

**The error I get when trying to execute the code made with msbuild**

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at MyProj.V2.Infrastructure.Bootstrappring.BootstrapperBase+<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<RegisterInfrastructureComponents>b__0(AutoMapper.IMapperConfigurationExpression)
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.Build(System.Action`1<AutoMapper.IMapperConfigurationExpression>)
   at AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(System.Action`1<AutoMapper.IMapperConfigurationExpression>)
...
```

It could indicate that some assemblies are missing or the references is broken when building with msbuild. I checked all the .dll thats references in the code is in the output in both scenarios.

Comment: Give a try my answer. Hope it helps. And if possible, can you share a simple sample of your project, so that I can check it directly, or share it by one-drive, I'll build and check it on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:
1.Use the msbuild.exe from:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\VSversion\MSBuild\15.0\Bin
```

2.Remove the space in "Any CPU", it should be like Platform="AnyCPU" instead of "Any CPU"

3.Uncheck the Optimize code to see if there has a difference